# Applying dtw on mfcc

Tags: matlab, speech-recognition, mfcc

I have calculated 26 MFCCs for two sample speech data. My mfcc matrices thus contain 26 columns and 120 rows each, where 120 is the number of frames. Now I want to apply DTW on them and I am doing this (on MATLAB):

```
mfcc1=mfcc1';
mfcc2=mfcc2';
M=simmx(mfcc1,mfcc2);
[p,q,c]=dp(1-M);
v=c(size(c,1),size(c,2))
```

which I have taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949679/how-to-compare-two-mfcc-feature-vector-or-similarity-between-the-mfcc-feature-ve)

But I don't quite understand why the similarity matrix and why it has to be `1-M` ?

Also if I exclude the first co-efficient, the result becomes totally invalid i.e it seems the first co-efficient is mandatory for DTW.

Is there something wrong with my approach? If it is, then how can I make it right?

**dp.m**

```
function [p,q,D] = dp(M)
% [p,q] = dp(M) 
%    Use dynamic programming to find a min-cost path through matrix M.
%    Return state sequence in p,q
% 2003-03-15 dpwe@ee.columbia.edu

% Copyright (c) 2003 Dan Ellis <dpwe@ee.columbia.edu>
% released under GPL - see file COPYRIGHT

[r,c] = size(M);

% costs
D = zeros(r+1, c+1);
D(1,:) = NaN;
D(:,1) = NaN;
D(1,1) = 0;
D(2:(r+1), 2:(c+1)) = M;

% traceback
phi = zeros(r,c);

for i = 1:r; 
  for j = 1:c;
    [dmax, tb] = min([D(i, j), D(i, j+1), D(i+1, j)]);
    D(i+1,j+1) = D(i+1,j+1)+dmax;
    phi(i,j) = tb;
  end
end

% Traceback from top left
i = r; 
j = c;
p = i;
q = j;
while i > 1 & j > 1
  tb = phi(i,j);
  if (tb == 1)
    i = i-1;
    j = j-1;
  elseif (tb == 2)
    i = i-1;
  elseif (tb == 3)
    j = j-1;
  else    
    error;
  end
  p = [i,p];
  q = [j,q];
end

% Strip off the edges of the D matrix before returning
D = D(2:(r+1),2:(c+1));
```

**simmx.m**

```
function M = simmx(A,B)
% M = simmx(A,B)
%    calculate a sim matrix between specgram-like feature matrices A and B.
%    size(M) = [size(A,2) size(B,2)]; A and B have same #rows.
% 2003-03-15 dpwe@ee.columbia.edu

% Copyright (c) 2003 Dan Ellis <dpwe@ee.columbia.edu>
% released under GPL - see file COPYRIGHT

EA = sqrt(sum(A.^2));
EB = sqrt(sum(B.^2));

%ncA = size(A,2);
%ncB = size(B,2);
%M = zeros(ncA, ncB);
%for i = 1:ncA
%  for j = 1:ncB
%    % normalized inner product i.e. cos(angle between vectors)
%    M(i,j) = (A(:,i)'*B(:,j))/(EA(i)*EB(j));
%  end
%end

% this is 10x faster
M = (A'*B)./(EA'*EB);
```

Comment: What is `[p,q,c]=dp(1-M);` Can you provide the matlab reference for the `dp()` function, I googled but could not find it quickly. This will help me understand what is going on with `1-M`

Comment: @ruohoruotsi : Added the code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's unpack this code:

```
1    mfcc1=mfcc1';
2    mfcc2=mfcc2';
3    M=simmx(mfcc1,mfcc2);
4    [p,q,c]=dp(1-M);
5    v=c(size(c,1),size(c,2))
```

in line 3, `M=simmx(mfcc1,mfcc2);` is computing the [Cosine Similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity), i.e. normalized inner product or the cosine of the angle between them. Here are my comments about why the authors used `1-M` instead of `M`.

When computing dtw, you want to find the *lowest-cost* path through the "cost" matrix. Dan Ellis's implementation uses dynamic programming to find the lowest-cost path between the opposite corners of the cost matrix.

However ***Cosine Similarity*** (whose values are on the range `[-1,1]`) is not a [proper distance metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) (i.e. not strictly positive), but its complement, the ***Cosine Distance*** is more appropriate as a cost measure (i.e. strictly positive). The complement is computed by simply taking `1-M`.

The Wikipage https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity, elaborates a bit better: [image]

[image]

Finally, have a look at the author's (Dan Ellis) original code: https://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/matlab/dtw/
You can see the comments about `1-M` as well as the matrix he uses to illustrate the the lowest cost path. Good luck!